# How to read raw contents of a file in flash as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, binary-data

I'm working on a project and I need to read raw contents of the current playing swf file.
I tried LoadVars but it has problems when reaching a byte with value of 0 and stops reading the file.

Is there any way to read raw contents of a file in flash as2 ? 
like this:

```
FileBytes = ReadFileRaw( "movie.swf" )
FileBytes.getByte(19) // for example!
```